# Ros Programming how to open my saved map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I have a problem. I am beginner at ROS Programming. I use RVIZ for mapping.

1. I mapped with Turtlebot using this tutorial: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM) . Then **next day** I tried to open my map using this tutorial: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Autonomously%20navigate%20in%20a%20known%20map) but my map didn't open. I can't understand how I will solve this problem.
2. I see that Turtlebot can't localize itself truly on the map when after I open the map **at the same day**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196471/ros-programming-how-to-open-my-saved-map/) by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-11-02**:
do you see map in rviz ? or map is not loaded ?

**Comment by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on 2014-11-02**:
For the first question, map file does not appear in directory which i saved map, this situation happens when i shut down the computer.
For the second question map is loaded but robot can not find its location on the appearing map.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-11-02**:
for 2. are you able to see localisation running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosrun map_server map_saver -f /tmp/my_map`

saves my_map.pgm in `/tmp` folder which will be cleared on every reboot.

just do `rosrun map_server map_saver -f my_map` ,it will save map in current folder

or change saving path. `rosrun map_server map_saver -f /..your..path.../my_map`

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on 2014-11-02**:
Thank you very much !!  I solved the problem in the first question. In the second question, while running robot can localize truly. Robot moves in wrong directions but after I closed the map.

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-11-03**:
so you solved 2 also ? if not ,I didn't get what is problem with localisation.

**Comment by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on 2014-11-03**:
Localisation problem : When i move forward robot by using teleoperation, it goes wrong direction in map.

**Comment by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on 2014-11-03**:
In rviz, there are global and local maps, when robot moves, global map coordinates does not change but local ones change, so which coordinates should i use to move robot from somewhere to another where.